What will a typical day in eternal life look like?
I'm old atheist and I'm going to die soon. I never enjoyed life, not then, not now, and I'm happy to die and disappear.
A missionary told me that if I accept Jesus, I will have eternal life, but was unable to explain me what that exactly entails.
I read the New Testament and found it lacking in details. Will I reborn in this same old planet? What about climate change? Must I work? What activities/hobbies will I pursue?
Please, only Bible quotations.
Answers
I didn't accept any answer; all lacks any level of detail. It all comes down to this:
It will be fantastic; trust me.
I don't how, I don't where,
but trust me, I will be amazing anyway.

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. I'm pleased to see you have asked for Bible quotations, but I'm afraid your question is likely to elicit opinion-based answers - which is not what we look for.  Care to add a tag which singles out a particular denomination within Christianity, or which at least narrows it down to some branch of Christianity?

Please take our Tour: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

So christian doesn't agree themselves on this matter?

@Lesley: Surely "eternal life" is not "opinion-based"?

There are different opinions about what eternal life means. For example, whereas most Christians want to spend eternity with God, and He resides in heaven, some want to spend eternity on a paradise earth. Others think everybody will be saved and there is no such thing as a place of eternal darkness. And then some think those who rejected Jesus will be annihilated. It's not straightforward as you can see from some of the related articles on the right-hand-side of this page. Nobody knows what a "typical day" in eternity will look like.

@Corbin - There are lots of opinions about what eternal life "will look like" depending if you are mainstream Christian, or a Jehovah's Witness, or a Latter Day Saint, or a Pentecostal, or a Swedenborgian. That's why this question needs to specify a denomination, or ask for a comparison between different denominations.

I'm going to reply to many of your points in an Answer, but meanwhile, you might want to read https://www.gotquestions.org/doing-in-Heaven.html.

Death is not the end of everything as people continue to exist as spirits in a state of rest after they die. If you read the Bible about what Saul did when he consulted a medium at Endor to raise Samuel from the dead, the spirit of Samuel rose and prophesied , we become spirits awaiting the resurrection and judgment

Always better than the day before, for eternity, it will get better every day.

Whether you go to heaven or hell, you will exist as a disembodied soul, retaining only your intellect and will, and none of your bodily senses or passions, until the day of the Resurrection, which will be the last day in history. Then, you will be resurrection and joined eternally to your body, and will either have bliss or torment forever, depending on which reward your earthly life has merited.

@jaredad7 My own tired and sick body or a celestial body? I will go to heaven or to a new earth? How will my intellect survive without my body?  I have a passion for learning, will I lost it? Please, provide citations.

@CandidMoe I can't create a full answer because the question is closed and I can't give an answer, so I won't be able to fit citations, but to quickly answer the questions (and this is in line with Catholic dogma, if you want to research it; you can find the catechism online for free). The body will be glorified if you are among the blessed, and will remain weak and frail if you are damned. We will all be in a physical place, having bodies. Your intellect and will are contained in the immaterial soul, so they survive separation from the body, and your personality is retained.

@jaredad7. I tried to read the catholic catechism, and I found it, like your comment, full of nice words, beautiful crafted sentences and no discernible meaning at all. Many quotes from Councils, Synods and speeches by the Pope, St. Augustine, Thomas Aquinas and other fathers of the Church, and no quotes from the Bible (there may be some, but I got bored of looking)

@CandidMoe this is a bit rude. The implication here is that I'm essentially saying nothing at all, except that's manifestly not true.

@jaredad7. I tried to be polite, but the truth has rough edges.

@CandidMoe it is not simply impolite, but uncharitable and plain false, so couching it in terms of "the truth" is both stupid and arrogant.

@jaredad7 Uncharitable, false, stupid and arrogant. You win.

@CandidMoe I'm not really interested in winning anything. I engaged at first in good faith, until you proved you were just here to troll, at which point I told you exactly what kind of behavior you were exhibiting.

First off, the Bible does not promote reincarnation, so you won’t be coming back in another life onto this same old planet. Before you contemplate “what eternal life will look like” first you have to understand where your eternal destination will be.  Here are a few sobering thoughts for you to take on board. After death we will all face judgment.

… man is destined to die once, and after that to face judgment (Hebrews 9:27).

We are judged on what we did while still alive. This is what Jesus said in Matthew 12:36:

I tell you that men will have to give account on the day of judgment for every careless word they have spoken. For by your words you will be acquitted, and by your words you will be condemned (Matthew 12:36-37).

There is no escaping this judgment either:

For we will all stand before God’s judgment seat…  So then each of us will give an account of himself to God (Romans 14:10-12).

As for this planet, God has plans for it.  At the end of this age the heavens and the earth we are familiar with will be no more:

The heavens will disappear with a roar; the elements will be destroyed by fire, and the earth and everything in it will be laid bare… That day will bring about the destruction of the heavens by fire, and the elements will melt in the heat (2 Peter 3: 10-12).

However, there is good news!

But in keeping with his promise we are looking forward to a new heaven and a new earth, the home of righteousness (2 Peter 3:13).

What will eternal life be like in this “home of righteousness”?  Pretty cool for those who are acquitted on the day of judgment.  Not so for those who are condemned because they rejected Christ Jesus and failed to repent and turn to God.
I hope this helps to show that the details of what eternal life will be like are meaningless unless your life in the here and now is in line with the requirements of a holy and righteous God who can never turn a blind eye to sin.  Perhaps now it is time for you to take your mortality seriously and check out the options that face each and every one of us.
This view is held by Reformed Protestants.
Now please add a tag such as Protestantism, or Catholicism, or anything that will prevent your question from being closed down.

I can't phantom what a "new earth" means. Do you?

BTW, according to Matthew 25:23, I'm already saved. Knowing/accepting Jesus is not a requirement for salvation.

What about the worthless, wicked, lazy servant in Matthew 25 verse 30? BTW, the parable is not speaking of material wealth but of spiritual wealth. As for the "new earth" there is a description of it in Revelation chapter 21. It describes how God himself will dwell with his people and there will be no tears, or pain or death - but it speaks of spiritual things. We can't imagine what it will be like, but I am sure it will surpass our wildest expectations. To be saved one has to believe in and place their faith in Christ Jesus and follow him. Are you doing that?

I multiplied my talents tenfold. The world is a little bit better because of my good deeds. I'm saved. I can be an atheist and still be a good, decent human being.

Congratulations! Well done you! There aren't enough good, decent human beings around. But do you even WANT to spend eternity in the presence of your Creator so you can worship Him forever? Will you enter through the narrow gate and humble yourself and follow Christ? Or do you think your charitable acts will earn you the right to spend eternity with him? Do you even KNOW him and are prepared to suffer for righteousness' sake? Or will he say to you "Get away, I never knew you." Good deeds don't save anyone from the judgment to come. Hey, but don't quit being a good, decent human being.

I don't want to live forever. I found that unappealing. Furthermore, the one who I'm, the one who is talking to you now, will disappear when my brain die, as my mind is a product of my physical existence. There will nothing left to be saved or condemn. Even if there is something like a soul, soul is not me anymore than my fingernails; why should I care what happens to it?

Souls are usually defined in terms of their function to be bearer of our identities. That's why if souls do indeed exist, then you probably would have good reasons to care about them. Not only that, but I'd also point out that if souls exist, then materialism is pretty much falsified (souls are almost always taken to be immaterial). So in that scenario, you would have good reasons to abandon materialist view of personal identity.

@CandidMoe I didn't realise you were asking on behalf of a friend, and not for yourself. Matthew and Mike Borden have given very good answers to your questions.

Let's see what misconceptions we can dispel (taken not just from the Question, but also from comments):

Christians bet their entire existence on a prize they know nothing about.

This is a gross misrepresentation. We don't know every detail, true, but we know we will have restored and perfected bodies, and we know we will be with God. We have many, many assurances that this existence will be wonderful in ways we can't even comprehend at this time.
In any case, thinking of it as a "prize" isn't the best attitude. Those who seek out of greed will be disappointed. The real question isn't "where will we go?", but "do we want to be with God?". For those who love Him, being eternally apart from God is unthinkable.

The one who [I am], the one who is talking to you now, will disappear when my brain die, as my mind is a product of my physical existence.

This is a very Materialist perspective, and is flatly contradicted by Scripture. Even modern science doesn't claim to entirely understand consciousness. Scripture, meanwhile, says that, while our bodies are physical, our essence, our "souls", are spirit and live on though our bodies die. Thus, according to Scripture, the belief that you will necessarily cease to exist when your body stops working is false.

I [am] happy to die and disappear.

You might. You might not. There is disagreement over what happens to unbelievers, namely, whether they suffer for eternity or (at some point) cease to exist. Personally, I believe your desire for the latter makes it more likely if it is an option at all, but do you really want to bet eternity on that?

Will I reborn in this same old planet?

Certainly not. Scripture describes a new Heaven and a new Earth. "The whole [present] creation has been groaning together in the pains of childbirth until now." (Romans 8:22) It was Cursed because of the Fall (Genesis 3). It will be recreated as it was meant to be, free from death and decay, and will be a better place. Disease, suffering and death will be no more.
We don't know exactly what this New Earth will be like, but that it will be recognizable and comfortable, and will have plants and water, is almost certain. Isaiah (11:6-9) speaks of animals that no longer hunt and kill. There may or may not be a sun (Revelation 7:16, 22:5), or oceans (Revelation 21:1). There will be at least one city, but no pollution, nor will it feel crowded.

What about climate change?

It's true that the climate can change, but God assures us that "while the earth remains, seedtime and harvest, cold and heat, summer and winter, day and night, shall not cease." (Genesis 8:22) The idea that we humans can affect the climate to such a degree as to render Earth uninhabitable is a) hubris, and b) a claim put forth by those who would deny God's existence and base their models on conjectures that are contradicted by Scripture. For that matter, some believe that Earth's climate is, in fact, improving. This is getting a bit into the weeds, however, and is an incredibly complex topic in its own right. The short version is that, no, you don't need to worry about "climate change" in the New Creation.

Must I work?

I wouldn't count on laying in bed all day and having food brought to you... although whether or not you will need to eat is disputed. However, various Scriptures suggest that food will be so plentiful that one need merely reach for it. This would suggest that you don't "need" to work. Even so, keep in mind that the toil of work will be no more. I would consider it likely that you will work, but will enjoy doing so because it will not be boring, tiring or stressful. Even in this life, many who don't need to work choose to do so.

What activities/hobbies will I pursue?

This is the most difficult question to answer, as I don't believe anyone really knows. It seems almost certain that you will worship God, as there are many examples given of His People worshiping him. I don't believe, however, that this will feel like an obligation, but rather will be something you want to do, akin to hugging a loved one. I also couldn't say whether all people will worship continuously, or whether there will be places of worship that people drift in and out of as the mood strikes them.

The world is a little bit better because of my good deeds. I'm saved.
Knowing Jesus is not a requisite.

Scripture is very clear that those who place their trust in their own works are going to be... "disappointed" when they stand in Judgment. No matter how good your deeds are (and to be sure, good deeds are commendable), your sin is worse. Without a Savior, all your good works are for naught.
The Good News is that God did send His Son to bear the penalty of your sin (and mine, and everyone's), "that whoever believes in Him should not perish but have eternal life". (John 3:16b) Only those who trust in this Promise and who seek the Lord are saved, but also those are the only requirements. Do not put your hope in earthly things or your own works, but trust in Him who alone has the power to Save.

Fair and very representative of a wide swath of mainstream Christianity.  +1

I'm asking "for a friend", not for me. If you can edit your answer and remove all reference to me, that will make it acceptable. It's not about me.

@CandidMoe, the Question certainly isn't worded that way... Anyway, feel free to read "you" as "a hypothetical reader" and not take it personally.  Same as you are apparently using "I" to be a hypothetical seeker and not yourself.

@Matthew. My bad. English is not my first language. I tried to write it in impersonal form but result was not good. Also, I must avoid speak in personal terms, which invite answers that evade the point. I want answers, not advice about how to live my life.


And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent." John 17:3

Eternal life is not a place. It is a relationship which can take place in any place.  Animated physical existence apart from a relationship with the Creator is just that... mere animated existence... it is not life in the biblical sense.
Physical death of the animated person is the result of the incursion of sin into humanity. But it is a picture, a parable in flesh of a deeper reality. Adam lost eternal life when he rebelled against God (he forsook God's knowledge in favor of his own) and God prolonged his physical life so that he would have an opportunity to repent and believe.
This is where we are, physical beings animated by the merciful power of God as he calls us to return to Him through Christ.
If the question is asking what heaven is like or what the new heavens and the new Earth will be like there are several passages which speak of it and several denominational interpretations.
If the question is asking what eternal life is like, then Jesus has answered it. It is knowing God the Father and Jesus Christ, whom he has sent.  In the here and now and in the hereafter that is eternal life.

Can someone tell me what a typical day in eternal life will look like?
We are all Pilgrims in a land not designed to be our true home. Christians worthy of eternal life strive to obtain the everlasting prize of enjoying the Beatific Vision in heaven. Contemplating God forever and in total spiritual joy and thanksgiving.
While on earth , we can only know a glimmer of what it will be like in heaven. Even St. Paul the Apostle is vague on what heaven will be like.

But, as it is written: That eye hath not seen, nor ear heard, neither hath it entered into the heart of man, what things God hath prepared for them that love him. - 1 Corinthians 2:9

Again St. Paul is equally mysterious about what heaven will be like as we see in the 12th chapter of 2 Corinthians.

12 If I must glory (it is not expedient indeed), but I will come to visions and revelations of the Lord.
2 I know a man in Christ above fourteen years ago (whether in the body, I know not, or out of the body, I know not; God knoweth), such a one caught up to the third heaven.
3 And I know such a man (whether in the body, or out of the body, I know not: God knoweth),
4 That he was caught up into paradise, and heard secret words, which it is not granted to man to utter.
5 For such an one I will glory; but for myself I will glory nothing, but in my infirmities. - 2 Corinthians 1-5

In heaven, the Blessed we spend their eternity (not time), adoring Almighty God in ways we can only imagine. In heaven, since time does not exist days do not exist.
What the banquet of the Lord will truely look like, only the blessed know and they are not sharing details of what the prize looks like.

I am sorry you are an atheist, but you are at least honest.  Thank God you are asking questions.
Yes, this life has many trials and the world is getting worse, but Jesus is coming soon. He will not set up anything on the earth as it will be in ruins, but He will take those who love Him to His home in Heaven.
The believers will be so happy when they see Jesus in the sky with millions of holy angels as they know their bodies will be changed into eternal youth, immortal and beautiful. 1 Corinthians 15:51-54. 1 Thessalonians 4:16-18. Isaiah 25:8.9.
All their tears and pain will be taken away. There will be no more death or sickness ever again.  Revelation 21:4.
As to what a normal day in eternity will look like, we do not know, but it will be wonderful.  1 Corinthians 2:9.  Only those who go there will know.
Dear Atheist, if you  remain in that mind set you will miss out on all I have written, whereas if I am wrong we both will not have missed out on anything because you have nothing in your future but the cold earth --'Dust to dust.'
God loves you so much He allowed His only begotten Son to take your death penalty and die a very painful and cruel death. This means your penalty has been paid.  There will be a judgment and if you have not chosen the precious gift God has given, you cannot have anything I have written about.
I feel sad for you because when you come up in the 2nd resurrection, you will have to face the verdict of your judgment. There will be fire, but it will only last as long as God's justice demands.  Revelation 20:11-15.  There will only be ashes left. Malachi 4:1-3.  An eternal hell makes God a monster, which He is not.
I plead with you dear brother/sister, give your life to Jesus and you will be blessed for eternity.  If not, when you die, it will be dust to dust, but after you are raised, you will die the final death, then it will be ashes to ashes. There is no resurrection.
But before you die, you will remember those who have tried to help you and  will be heartbroken you did not accept it.  Please look to Jesus and accept His wonderful gift of salvation.
God says, "I have no pleasure in the death of him that dieth, saith the Lord God, wherefore turn yourself and live..." Ezekiel 18:32.
God loves you.  Jesus loves you.

May I suggest you break this up into paragraphs, divding the text into steps in your argument. Many will not read a 'wall of text' such as this and your contribution will not receive the attention which it may deserve. Please see the Tour and the Help, also. Welcome to SE-C.

If you are NOT saved (which is the case for you), you spend eternity in HELLFIRE.
Luke 16:22-24 And it came to pass, that the beggar died, and was carried by the angels into Abraham's bosom: the rich man also died, and was buried; And in hell he lift up his eyes, being in torments, and seeth Abraham afar off, and Lazarus in his bosom. And he cried and said, Father Abraham, have mercy on me, and send Lazarus, that he may dip the tip of his finger in water, and cool my tongue; for I am tormented in this flame.
If you are saved, you spend eternity in Heaven.
Revelation 21:1-4 And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away; and there was no more sea. And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down from God out of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband. And I heard a great voice out of heaven saying, Behold, the tabernacle of God is with men, and he will dwell with them, and they shall be his people, and God himself shall be with them, and be their God. And God shall wipe away all tears from their eyes; and there shall be no more death, neither sorrow, nor crying, neither shall there be any more pain: for the former things are passed away.
Revelation 21:23-27 And the city had no need of the sun, neither of the moon, to shine in it: for the glory of God did lighten it, and the Lamb is the light thereof. And the nations of them which are saved shall walk in the light of it: and the kings of the earth do bring their glory and honour into it. And the gates of it shall not be shut at all by day: for there shall be no night there. And they shall bring the glory and honour of the nations into it. And there shall in no wise enter into it any thing that defileth, neither whatsoever worketh abomination, or maketh a lie: but they which are written in the Lamb's book of life.
If you ARE saved, you spend eternity in the New Jerusalem. There will be no more sorrow, tears, suffering, pain, death, or any of the negative aspects of this world. This means no more extreme weather (extreme hot or cold) and it will be better than the Garden of Eden.
How to get saved?
1st Corinthians 15:1-4 Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand; By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain. For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures; And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

Matthew 25:23 says that I'm already saved, because I feed the hungry. Knowing Jesus is not a requisite

Acording to Päul, the price of sin is death (Roman 6:23), not eternal punishment in a lake of fire.

@CandidMoe Do you feed the hungry as an act of faith in God through Christ?  If not, it is sin. Romans 14:23

@MikeBorden Paul is talking about unclean foods. Not applicable.

@CandidMoe Paul is bringing a general principle to bear on a particular topic. Please see Hebrews 11:6.

@MikeBorden You are always citing Paul, never Jesus. Weird

@CandidMoe. Always?  I have just met you sir.

@CandidMoe How about John 3:17 -19

@MikeBorden. Off topic. We are talking about eternal life.

@CandidMoe "And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent.". John 17:3... Jesus again.

@MikeBorden That don't answer my question.
